# C# TcpSockets Do I disconnect the clean/proper way?

Tags: c#, sockets, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, asyncsocket

So i know there are a lot of articles out there on this topic and i did read a lot of them i would say but for some reason im sure my code is not doing what it is supposed to do.

I want to close a connection between my Server and my Client.
Now on the serverside i start the disconnect with this code

```
public void shutdown()
    {
        _socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        _socket.Close();
    }
```

And on the Client side i have some troubles understanding how i get to the disconnect what i believe is happening is the following: in my async receive callback i should get an error since the server started a shutdown sequence and i have to handle that (right???) so my code for the client looks like this:
ReceiveCallback:

```
private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        int bytesRecieved = 0;
        byte[] tempBuff;

        //Try to receive But if a Socket error occures disconnect otherwise start Receiving again
        try
        {
            bytesRecieved = _socket.EndReceive(result);
        }
        catch (SocketException sockEx)
        {
            Disconnect(sockEx);
            return;
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException disposeEx)
        {
            Disconnect(disposeEx);
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StartReceive();
            return;
        }

        if (bytesRecieved == 0)
        {
            StartReceive();
            return;
        }

        tempBuff = new byte[bytesRecieved];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(_buffer, 0, tempBuff, 0, bytesRecieved);
        StartReceive();
        _packHandler.handlePacket(tempBuff);

    }
```

Disconnect:

```
public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (!_socket.Connected)
        {
            return;
        }
        _socket.BeginDisconnect(false, DisconnectCallback, null);
    }
```

DisconnectCallback

```
private void DisconnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        _socket.EndDisconnect(result);
        _socket.Close();
    }
```

(The Disconnect Method is overloaded so if i get an exception it puts up a messageBox and then also calls Disconnect. Just so i know what happened.)

Where am i wrong and what can i improve uppon ???

I tried the code and it seemed to work but i then looked with netstat if all sockets are closed and the client socket was not. It was in FIN_WAIT_2 which means that it (or the server???) did not yet send the FIN packet right ?
Oh and then i tried it again with this line changed:

```
if (bytesRecieved == 0)
        {
            StartReceive();
            return;
        }
```

TO

```
if (bytesRecieved == 0)
        {
            Disconnect;
            return;
        }
```

which then threw an exception on the serverside and on the clientside the client said that the connection was closed by the server ???

EDIT: Even when i have closed both Programs Netstat still shows the port in a WAITING status. what does that tell me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important is:

- If a server starts a shutdown sequence you DO have to handle it
- Both sides have to call shutdown on their socket
- You need a way to notice the disconnect (it does not give you an error, or least it didnt for me)

Therefor I created my own class customSocket which inherits from Socket

```
public class customSocket : Socket
{
    #region Properties
    private readonly Timer _timer;
    private const int _interval = 1000;

    private bool Connected
    {
        get
        {
            bool part1 = Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
            bool part2 = (Available == 0);
            if (part1 && part2)
                return false;
            else 
                return true;
        }
    }

    public bool EventsEnabled
    {
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                _timer.Start();
            }
            else
                _timer.Stop();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public customSocket(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType sockType, ProtocolType protocolType)
        : base(addressFamily, sockType, protocolType)
    {
        _timer = new Timer { Interval = _interval };
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerTick;
    }

    public customSocket(SocketInformation sockInfo)
        : base(sockInfo)
    {
        _timer = new Timer { Interval = _interval };
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerTick;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Events

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Socket_disconected;
    public void Raise_Socket_disconnected()
    {
        EventHandler<EventArgs> handler = Socket_disconected;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this,new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Connected)
        {
            Raise_Socket_disconnected();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This version of a socket has an Event for a disconnect.
Now if you create an instance of your socket class you have to connect the handler and set the EventsEnabled true.

This handler then calls the shutdown and your socket does not stay in FIN_WAIT_2

Answer (score 1):

Your normal disconnect has a shutdown which will clear the socket so it can disconnect properly but your async style never calls shutdown.  I added it in a convenient location below.

```
public void Disconnect()
{
    if (!_socket.Connected)
    {
        return;
    }
    _socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both); // Make sure to do this
    _socket.BeginDisconnect(false, DisconnectCallback, null);
}
```

**EDIT:**

From the sounds of it you don't have a reason to be using the Async Method?  The async methods are so you can send data in a separate execution thread freeing up your thread to do some data processing for instance while that occurs.

I don't see any processing going on so I suggest you change disconnect like this and see if it resolves the problem.  Because I don't think you are waiting on the Async methods which will not work out well.

```
public void Disconnect()
{
    if (!_socket.Connected)
    {
        return;
    }
    shutdown(); //Your standard disconnect that you showed up top.  Scoping might be required.
}
```

A bit of data on Async can be scrounged up here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38dxf7kt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply.
Could you explain what exctly happens when i call shutdown and then what happens with the beginDisconnect and what is the difference between sync sockets and async sockets for this disconnect ?

Comment: UPDATE: I tried it but the socket is still open.
EDIT : Now my server also crashes with an exception saying the client closed the connection already the moment i stop my server

Comment: I think you are using the Async methods mixed in a bad way and not waiting on them.  Anyway I edited and explained some above.

Comment: Ok i guess you are right i dont want to do any processing anymore so i change that back to sync i still have that one open socket in FIN_WAITING_2 though it goes to WAITING if i close the client application
EDIT: but i also get a exception if i add a line _socket.Close() after the shutdown in the client and in that moment my server crashes but if you look with netstat it says that the connection status is CONNECTED ????

Comment: You have a _socket.Close() inside of your shutdown function so calling it again would give an exception.

Comment: On the server side yes but not on the client side ? shouldn't it be like server does a shutdown then the client does a shutdown then both do a Close ???

Comment: You might add _socket.Dispose() after your _socket.Close in shutdown though.  See if that helps, always good to dispose anyway.

Comment: Socket still in FIN_WAITNG_2

Comment: It does look like your client is all async above, I mixed that piece up.  Are you using EventWaitHandles or something to know when those pieces have processed? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think trying to do the async call within an async call is the issue.  You should handle those from a main thread.

Comment: Ok instead of trieng to redo my version how is it normally done ??? which functions have to be called in wich order on wich side so it does what i want ????